# On General Definition of Sobolev Spaces

Tags: definition, sobolev-spaces

This might be trivial, but why a Sobolev space is generally defined with respect to an open set and not to a closed set or more generally? Is it related to the differentiability concept?

P.S.: The point I've said about the definition of a Sobolev space with respect to an open set can be supported by the following references:

1. Tartar, 2007. An Introduction to Sobolev Spaces and Interpolation Spaces.
2. https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Extension_by_zero

And one seeming exception can be seen here: https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/frey/cours/UdC/ma691/ma691_ch2.pdf (or maybe it is not well-defined)

Thanks

Comment: On page 2 the set $\Omega$ has smooth boundary so it’s not just bounded

Comment: I would like to consider a generalization. But considering that, do you know if there is a reference for a definition of a Sobolev space with respect to a set with those conditions?

Comment: Well when the set is that nice, as the $L^p$ norms, $p\in[1,\infty]$ don't depend on measure zero sets like $\partial \Omega$,  you are free to use their closure instead. I guess this is why you won't find anyone making a fuss about this.  Its not clear from what you wrote that you are generalising the definition of the first link, maybe edit?Musings - taking $U$ closed would make $L^p_{\text{loc}}(U) = L^p(U)$; Evans, which defines $H^k_0$ and relates to traces when $\partial U\in C^1$ only, also makes a distinction between $C( U^\circ)$ and $C(\overline U)$ , which I think is reasonable.

Comment: It would be very helpful a general description of why it is possible the definition of some Sobolev spaces on  closed sets which it is displayed here: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82662377.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the additional paper; but if it was your intention that I read and understand this paper, I simply don't have the motivation or the time right now. If this is your end goal, maybe put it in the question? PS re:your 'seeming exception', it seems to say that if I set $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$, $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$, then $f\in C^0([0,1])$, a statement I cannot agree with

Comment: @CalvinKhor, thanks for your comments.

Comment: I did glance, and it seems that the contribution of the paper is an intrinsic description of   the restriction of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ functions to closed sets. As mentioned in the introduction, by Morrey's inequality, for the range that paper is considering $p>n$, it is classical that $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ is a subspace of $C^0(\mathbb R^n)$, and $C^0$ functions can be naturally restricted to any subset. I'll remark that the paper carefully writes $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)|_S$ rather than $W^{1,p}(S)$; i see no attempt at defining $W^{1,p}(S)$ in this paper